# How can I detect which audio channels in a video file are silent using FFMPEG?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I need to be able to scan video files and report which audio tracks/channels are silent without knowing anything about the file's audio mapping ahead of time.  I have tried this ffmpeg (v4.1) command on a file that contains 16 audio channels:

```
$ ffmpeg -i foo5.mxf -map 0:a -af astats -f null -
...
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:2 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:3 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:4 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:6 -> #0:5 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:7 -> #0:6 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:8 -> #0:7 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:9 -> #0:8 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:10 -> #0:9 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:11 -> #0:10 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:12 -> #0:11 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:13 -> #0:12 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:14 -> #0:13 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:15 -> #0:14 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
  Stream #0:16 -> #0:15 (pcm_s24be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
...
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Channel: 1
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] DC offset: 0.000070
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Min level: -170426368.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Max level: 172195840.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Min difference: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Max difference: 58281984.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Mean difference: 3089081.855667
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] RMS difference: 4825348.720329
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Peak level dB: -21.918144
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] RMS level dB: -34.035425
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] RMS peak dB: -27.320939
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] RMS trough dB: -48.414915
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Crest factor: 4.035190
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Flat factor: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Peak count: 2
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Bit depth: 20/20
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Dynamic range: 98.493854
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Zero crossings: 10216
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Zero crossings rate: 0.042383
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Overall
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] DC offset: 0.000070
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Min level: -170426368.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Max level: 172195840.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Min difference: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Max difference: 58281984.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Mean difference: 3089081.855667
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] RMS difference: 4825348.720329
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Peak level dB: -21.918144
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] RMS level dB: -34.035425
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] RMS peak dB: -27.320939
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] RMS trough dB: -48.414915
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Flat factor: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Peak count: 2.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Bit depth: 20/20
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Number of samples: 241040
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Channel: 1
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] DC offset: 0.000070
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Min level: -170426368.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Max level: 172199936.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Min difference: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Max difference: 58277888.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Mean difference: 3089075.891088
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] RMS difference: 4825346.346176
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Peak level dB: -21.917938
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] RMS level dB: -34.035425
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] RMS peak dB: -27.320942
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] RMS trough dB: -48.414908
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Crest factor: 4.035287
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Flat factor: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Peak count: 2
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Bit depth: 20/20
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Dynamic range: 98.494061
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Zero crossings: 10220
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Zero crossings rate: 0.042400
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Overall
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] DC offset: 0.000070
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Min level: -170426368.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Max level: 172199936.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Min difference: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Max difference: 58277888.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Mean difference: 3089075.891088
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] RMS difference: 4825346.346176
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Peak level dB: -21.917938
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] RMS level dB: -34.035425
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] RMS peak dB: -27.320942
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] RMS trough dB: -48.414908
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Flat factor: 0.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Peak count: 2.000000
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Bit depth: 20/20
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Number of samples: 241040
...
```

By piping to grep (and a little more filtering) I can consolidate this and examine the peak levels on the audio channels:

```
$ ffmpeg -i foo5.mxf -map 0:a -af astats -f null - 2>&1 | grep -E "(Channel:|Peak level|Overall)"
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Channel: 1
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Peak level dB: -21.918144
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Overall
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x9123c0] Peak level dB: -21.918144
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Channel: 1
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Peak level dB: -21.917938
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Overall
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x4def40] Peak level dB: -21.917938
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0xb92180] Channel: 1
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0xb92180] Peak level dB: -6153.053111
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0xb92180] Overall
[Parsed_astats_0 @ 0xb92180] Peak level dB: -6153.053111
...
```

It gets me mostly what I need if I filter out peak levels < -120db.  The problem is it identifies all channels as "Channel 1".  Maybe this is because each audio stream only has a single channel in it.  But I find nothing in the original output to tie each "audio status section" (the part containing "Channel:" through "Sero crossings rate") to the associated stream (e.g., 0:0, 0:1, etc.).  Can I reliably deduce this just based on the order of the output?

Should I be using a different filter (instead of astats) or parameter set to get this info?

Comment: Per the `ffmpeg` tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on [su] or [video.se].